# JQuery .css() doesn't show div-block

Tags: jquery

I've made some code, which should display a div block, when a link is clicked, as far as I've understood.

The html:

```
<a href="#" id="show_1">attach more</a>
<div style="display:none" id="attached_1">
    Gogogo
</div>
```

And the script:

```
$(function() {
    $("#$show_1").on('click', function() {
        $("#attached_1").css('display', 'block');
    })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PXVXk/2/

But it doesn't seem to be working.

Can someone explain to me why this is?

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies - I don't know how I missed that... ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#show_1").on('click', function() {// on   $("#$show_1") chane in   $("#show_1")
        $("#attached_1").css('display', 'block');
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a `$` after `#` in `#$show_1` causing an `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #$show_1` error.

```
$(function() {
    $("#show_1").on('click', function() {
        $("#attached_1").show();
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Arefv/)

**Note: As a first step of debugging in client side scripting please check the browser console to see whether there are any errrors**

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even know about that tool - so helpful thanks!

Comment: @SimonMalone also instead of `.css('display', 'block');` use `.show()`

Answer (score 1):

you have extra `$` in selector, remove that, like change:

```
$("#$show_1").on('click', function() {
```

to

```
$("#show_1").on('click', function() {
```

Demo:: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PXVXk/4/)

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PXVXk/3/)

```
$(function() {
    $("#show_1").on('click', function() {
       ^//removed $ from here
        $("#attached_1").css('display', 'block');
    })
});
```

[id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in your syntax. It must be,

```
$(function() {
    $("#show_1").on('click', function() {
        $("#attached_1").css('display', 'block');
    })
});
```